# Skyrim, activating abilities

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I can't for the life of me figure out how to activate the High-Elf Highborn ability.

For that matter,  I have used scrolls in the past, but I've also failed to use them.

How do activate Highborn?

How do I use a scroll?

How do I use the abilities granted by ruins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do activate Highborn?

It will be under "Powers" in your menu with spells, shouts and active effects. Select it to make it active and use it with the right button (above the right trigger).

> How do I use a scroll?

They are wielded like weapons. Equip a scroll from your inventory, asign it to your left or right hand and fire away.

> How do I use the abilities granted by ruins?

Just click on the stone and confirm that you want to activate that perticuliar stone. The stones give always-on bonuses that do not need to be activated or used afterwards. Note that only one stone can be active at a time.

Comment: Danny, I try that, but it activates my shout.  The current rune I have found is supposed to allow me to raise 2 skeletons (or somehting like that) per day. Doesn't seem like it would always be active

Comment: @hvgotcodes Often you will find granted abilities like that under the 'Powers' menu. For instance the ghostly assassin I can summon is not under Conjuration but under Powers (go figure) as well as Beast Form for being a Werewolf. (This is also where my racial ability for being a Breton is located).

Answer (score 2):

To use any ability go to the **Magic** screen, in there you have **Powers** - all your powers and abilities will be listed there. Add any of them as Favorite then you can assign them from the quick menu while playing - same way as you equip weapon. When assigned, click <kbd>RB</kbd> button.

More controls can be found [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Controls).

As for scrolls, same way - they are accessible from within the Inventory, you have sub menu for them. You can either assign them directly from there, or have them as favorite then assign from the quick menu. Once assigned click <kbd>RB</kbd> to activate.